# Generic cast method returning base type (struct)

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'd like to write a method that cast a value (object) into a basic type (like string, int, double, etc..). I use this method in a routine that maps DataRows on objects.

I wrote this:

```
public static T CastObjectToBasicType<T>(DataRow row, string column)
    where T : struct
{
    object cellValue = row[column];

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        return ToString(cellValue);

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int) || typeof(T) == typeof(int?))
        return ToInt(cellValue);

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool) || typeof(T) == typeof(bool?))
        return ToBool(cellValue);

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(double) || typeof(T) == typeof(double?))
        return ToDouble(cellValue);

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(decimal) || typeof(T) == typeof(decimal?))
        return ToDecimal(cellValue);

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime) || typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime?))
        return ToDateTime(cellValue) ;

     throw new ArgumentException("T not supported");
}
```

where methods like ToString, ToBool, ToDouble, etc... are simple methods that convert input into the desidered type.

The code above doesn't compile; the problem is that I'm not able to cast the result into type T, because T is a struct and i cant use (for exaple)

```
return ToDouble(obj) as T;
```

neither

```
return (T) ToDouble(obj);
```

If i replace the clause

```
where T : struct
```

with

```
where T : class
```

then I'm not able to call the method using int, bool, double, etc... as T because them are not classes.

I don't know if there is a way to accomplish this; the alternative is to call directly the simple methods like ToBool, ToInt, etc... without passing from a generic method, but I prefer to have a single cast method.

Is there anything I can do? Any help would be appreciated, also alternatives.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you maybe just looking for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: Why do you need to specify a "where T: ..." at all?

Comment: You cannot convert an int or double to T, because the compiler does not know whether the T type has proper converters implemented.

Comment: You shouldn't use generics in this way, if you need ad-hoc specialisation for different types, use overloads.

Comment: `ToDouble(obj) as T` isn't too smart idead. Why would you do double conversion and why would you use `as` operator? It has different purpose.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt I already use the Convert class in the simple methods (ToInt, ToDouble, etc...)

Comment: @PeterSchneider in this case I want to limit the usage of the method only for struct

Comment: @Lee Maybe overloads are a valid alternative...I think i should give it a try!

Comment: @Tarec the conversion is made by ToInt, ToDouble, etc... methods. So I just want to convert the output in T to generalize the CastObjectToBasicType method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because, as far as the compiler knows, there's no possible conversion between `T` and, for example, `DateTime`.

Try upcasting `DateTime` to the only ancestor `DateTime` and `T` have in common - `object` - and then downcasting back to `T`.

```
return (T) (object) ToDouble(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks @dcastro, in this way works. I had to remove the where T : struct clause, otherwise I can not use the method with string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify a where T clause unless you actually want to limit to something (interface , class, struct etc). Here you don't, so just remove the where clause

Comment: In this case I want to limit the usage of the method only for struct (for example I don't want to pass a generic FooObject as T); however, I can remove the where clause as you suggest and make a check in the body of the method if (T == int || T == double ...<etc>...). But this doesn't resolve the casting problem.

Comment: In the end I had to remove the clause otherwise I can not use the method with string